# Permanently enabling authentication in MongoDB 2.x

Tags: mongodb

Once an admin user has been created in MongoDB (2.x), is there a property that can be set to turn on authentication permanently?  Since there isn't a default config file and the --auth flag can be avoided, I need a way to turn this on once and for all.

Comment: The way is called "Proper system administration" and is rather easy to do. As for Linux: Only root can fire up during system start and can modify the init-scripts, in which a configuration file or command line flag is given to mongod. Only root can become the mongodb system user to edit said config file. Others will need to help with Windows, but it should not be too different there.

Comment: thanks much.  that's what I needed to know.